# Getting 404 in Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: java, servlets

I am new learner of Java. I am trying to run my first servlet program.
I have been trying from the last 10-12 days. I have gone through all your answers, but I am still not able solve it.

My **Java file** is:

```
package mariyam;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class HelloWorld1 extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

**My web.xml:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mariyam.HelloWorld1</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorld1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The *HelloWorld1.class* file is copied to the location:

```
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\mariyam\WEB-INF\Classes
```

The web.xml file is present in:

```
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\mariyam\WEB-INF
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Are you running this on your local machine, ie localhost:8080/HelloWorld1 or is the servlet hosted elsewhere?

Comment: Yes I am running this on my local machine .Error message I am getting is HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWorld1  description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Are you copying the files manually?

Comment: Yes I am. copying .class manually on to the path  C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\mariyam\WEB-INF\Classes

Comment: Well, don't do it. Deploy it properly: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

By default, Tomcat does not serve your application in the root directory. The path contains the name of your application, so

```
http://localhost:8080/mariyam/HelloWorld1
```

would be the correct URL.

---

#### Setting up Tomcat autodeploy

If you didn't do this yet, you should set the `autoDeploy="true"` attribute at the `Host` element of `server.xml`, after this you only need to copy your `.war` file to `Tomcat/webapps` and start the server. This way, if your file is named `mariyam.war`, and it is a valid `.war` file, it should deploy to the URL I have specified above.

Comment: I have tried this way by entering URL http://localhost:8080/mariyam/HelloWorld1 but stil it doesn't work...

Comment: Are you sure that Tomcat is running?